# Can't play VCD and DVD in Ubuntu release 12.04 (Precise) 64-bit

Tags: dvd, vcd

I have tried playing VCDs and DVDs but I always get this type of error:

> File reading failed:
>   VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).

Answer (score 0):

You probably just miss some libraries for reading DVD. Ensure you have libdvdcss2, libdvdread4 and libdvdnav4 installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras libdvdread4 libdvdnav4
```

Then run:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: HI cUBI, I HVE TRIED LL THT BUT STILL THE SME ERROR,UNBLE TO PLY USING VLC

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras libdvdread4 libdvdnav4home@home-Aspire-V3-571G:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras libdvdread4 libdvdnav4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdvdnav4 is already the newest version.
libdvdnav4 set to manually installed.
libdvdread4 is already the newest version.
libdvdread4 set to manually installed.
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 129 not upgraded.

Comment: WHEN I TRY I GET THIS ERROR

Comment: File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).

Comment: run `vlc -vvv /media/[PATH_TO_MAIN_VOB_FILE]` from terminal and post the result